# How to make a div always on the left-most side of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make make a `div` always showing on the left-most side of the browser window, ], would you give me some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
div#mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

You'll probably want to add `top` or `bottom` to that as well so that it doesn't sit at the top of the screen.

Something like:

```
div#mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 200px; /* 200px from top */
}
```

or:

```
div#mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 200px; /* 200px from bottom */
}
```

or:

```
div#mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%; /* Half way down the side */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later and will accept the answer accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

set its `position` to `fixed` and its `left` to `0px`

```
#fixedLeft{
    position:fixed; /* now it will stay fixed on the screen, even while you scroll*/
    left:0px; /* it will be stuck to the left*/
    top:50%; /* it will be in the middle (vertically)*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gaby! Two answers are similar :)